# Tensorflow Recognize Flowers using transfer learning error generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I tried to follow this popular Tensorflow [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb#scrollTo=d8jyt37T42Vf).

Which basically should be a copy-paste, but I still get an error in my code.

I have tried use `None` as a shape but that does not work. And since I am very new at this I am not really sure what to google for.

This is the code where the error occurs;

```py
epochs = 10
history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    validation_data=val_generator)
```

I get this error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (59, 224, 224, 3) where an element of shape (64, 224, 224, 3) was expected.

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 221, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 621, in generator_py_func
    "of shape %s was expected." % (ret_array.shape, expected_shape))
```

Comment: @skipper Hm, there is just 64 as batch_size and not 59 in the notebook? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Came across the same issue. However, batch size is 64 for both train_generator and val_generator.

Comment: I have the same issue and this tutorial should be easy for the first try. I even don't know Python for fixing this...